# How to replace certain values in a queryset with Django?

Tags: mysql, django, join, django-queryset

i have these two models:

```
class Rfid(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    tag_id = models.CharField(db_column='Tag_ID', max_length=16, blank=True) # Field name made$
    site_id = models.CharField(db_column='Site_ID', max_length=8, blank=True) # Field name mad$
    time = models.IntegerField(db_column='Time', blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowe$
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'RFID'

class RfidNames(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    badge_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'RFID_names'
```

and in views i have this:

```
def rfid_lister(request):
    raw_scans = Rfid.objects.all().using('devices').order_by('-time')
    rfid_scan_list = list(raw_scans )

    return render_to_response("RFID_display.html",
                              locals(),
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in my template im just displaying the data from raw_scan which looks like this:

```
A11     8400340910  8/20/2014 15:37:22
A11     8400340910  8/20/2014 13:55:10
A11     8400340910  8/20/2014 13:51:53
A11     8400340910  8/20/2014 13:43:33
A11     35021E05AE  8/20/2014 13:39:58
A11     0500679CF9  8/20/2014 13:39:26
A11     0500679CF9  8/20/2014 13:39:24
```

however in the RfidNames table i have something like this:

```
name=bob, badge_id=8400340910
```

what im looking for is a way to render something that looks like this:

```
A11     bob         8/20/2014 15:37:22
A11     bob         8/20/2014 13:55:10
A11     bob         8/20/2014 13:51:53
A11     bob         8/20/2014 13:43:33
A11     35021E05AE  8/20/2014 13:39:58
A11     0500679CF9  8/20/2014 13:39:26
A11     0500679CF9  8/20/2014 13:39:24
```

any ideas on how this could be done using a queryset?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Rfid.tag_id is really a foreign key to RfidNames.badge_id. You should declare it as such: a foreign key field can just as easily be a char field.

```
class Rfid(models.Model):
    ...
    tag = models.ForeignKey('RfidNames', db_column='Tag_ID', to_field='badge_id', blank=True, null=True)
```

Now you can simply follow the relationship in the template:

```
{% for scan in scan_list %}
    {{ scan.site_id }}  {{ scan.tag.name }}  {{ scan.time }}
{% endfor %}
```

That incurs a db lookup per row, so you can use `select_related` in the view to make it significantly more efficient:

```
scan_list = Rfid.objects.all().using('devices').order_by('-time').select_related('RfidNames')
```

Note you don't need the explicit step of converting to a list, in any case.

Comment: That worked amazingly well! as an fyi for anyone else I had to add a comparison {% if obj.tag.name %} into the template to see if obj.tag.name was null and insert obj.tag_id if it was, but that gives me a little more control anyways so THANK YOU!!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you: it signals to future users that it solved the problem.